# MySQL Daemon issue

Tags: mysql, database, daemon, dedicated-server

I seem to be having an issue with my MySQL Daemon and a World-writable config file being ignored :S

Here's the output when I run mysqld as user mysql:

```
bash-4.2$ mysqld
Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
120730 17:57:34 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120730 17:57:34 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120730 17:57:34 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120730 17:57:34 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120730 17:57:34 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120730 17:57:34 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120730 17:57:34 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
```

Here's my 'my.cnf' file contents:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]

user        = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp

key_buffer              = 16M
thread_stack            = 128K
thread_cache_size   = 8
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 1024M
sort_buffer=512M
thread_concurrency=32
query_cache_type=2
tmp_table_size=1G

#log            = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#skip-innodb
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
```

Really have no clue where to go, does anyone know how to ouput verbose errors with mysqld? Or even better how to fix this issue? Any ideas? Thanks guys :)

Okay, the world-writable config file is solved, I need help with these errors now:

```
bash-4.2$ mysqld
120730 18:18:23 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/mysql/ks23085.lower-test
120730 18:18:23 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/mysql/ks23085.lower-test
120730 18:18:23 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
120730 18:18:23 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
120730 18:18:23 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120730 18:18:23 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120730 18:18:23 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120730 18:18:23 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120730 18:18:23 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120730 18:18:24 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120730 18:18:24  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I can't tell if it's to do with the directory not being permitted properly or something else, or is it the same problem as last time? :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The my.cnf should not be world-writable (i.e. **6 or **7) permissions.

It is a security vulnerability. MySQL will ignore files with this this permission setting.